# Limit Spring Boot WebMvcConfigurer to specified paths only

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I would like to configure asynchronous processing support for a subset of request mappings in my Spring Boot application which match `/async/*`. Examples:

- `localhost:8080/async/downloadLargeFile`
- `localhost:8080/async/longRunningRask`

Taking the first example, I have implemented my method as follows using [`StreamingResponseBody`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/StreamingResponseBody.html):

```
@GetMapping
public ResponseEntity<StreamingResponseBody> downloadLargeFile() throws IOException {
    long size = Files.size(path);
    InputStream inputStream = Files.newInputStream(path);
    return ResponseEntity.ok()
        .contentLength(size)
        .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=large_file.txt")
        .body(inputStream::transferTo);
}
```

In the documentation for `StreamingResponseBody`, it states I should be configuring an [`AsyncTaskExecutor`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/task/AsyncTaskExecutor.html), so I have this @Configuration class which implements [`WebMvcConfigurer`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/WebMvcConfigurer.html) as well:

```
@Configuration
public class AsyncConfigurer implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureAsyncSupport(AsyncSupportConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.setDefaultTimeout(-1);
        configurer.setTaskExecutor(asyncTaskExecutor());
    }

    @Bean
    public AsyncTaskExecutor asyncTaskExecutor() {
        return new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor("async");
    }
}
```

However, I cannot find a way to use this task executor only with requests that match a given pattern.

As a more general question - **how do I restrict the `WebMvcConfigurer` to apply only to a subset of requests matching a pattern**?

If this is not possible or not recommended, what is the proper way to accomplish the same behaviour?

Comment: Do you have more parts that use async in your application? This executor will only be used for the async part of the web application. Also you might not want to use the `SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor` but rather a threadpool based one.

Comment: Hi @M.Deinum, what do you mean by "the async part of the web application"? How is that defined exactly? Yes, I would like to use an `AsyncTaskExecutor` for other requests as well, but limiting it to working for just one would already be of assistance. Are you suggesting that I may want to use a pooled one if I have several async requests?

Comment: You want to limit the number of threads created, this one creates threads on the fly. The normal requests are handled by your servlet container, the async onces (like you have here) are passed on to the `TaskExecutor` you define, so that the regular request handling threads are free to handle other incoming requests again.

Comment: But how does the context know which requests are async and which ones are not - i.e. how does it know which task executor to route things to?

Comment: There is just 1 task executor for async task, other request are handled by the servlet container. The async stuff depends on the return type of your controller. Things like `Future`, `Flux`, or a `StreamingResponseBody` are handled async (check the spring documentation for that).

Comment: I see the following: "A controller method return value type for asynchronous request processing". However, I assumed this was just informing me that it CAN be used with async functionality, not that it IS used by default. Do you have a source for which return types are considered asynchronous? From line 718 of `RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java` it is not obvious which ones are async - in fact there is one literally called `AsyncTaskMethodRetrunValueHandler` and a separate one for `StreamingResponseBody`.

Comment: As stated the [Spring Framework Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-ann-async).

Comment: Thank you. Would you like to add an answer to this so other people can benefit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `TaskExecutor` when configured for/with the `WebMvcConfigurer` on the `AsyncSupportConfigurer` will solely be used for async processing of web requests. All other requests are handled by the default request handling threads as available on your servlet container.

The async nature is defined by the return type of your method. The async types are described in the [MVC Async](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-ann-async) part of the Spring Reference guide.